# std::set_intersection, Intersection list with offset

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I need get the intersection list between two vectors. And in my case vectors are vector of user type. So to get the number encapsulated I must use a comparer function.

Also I want to able get the intersection with a offSet. For example given two vectors  {1,2,3,4,6,8} and {5,  7,  9,10} . Intersection with offSet 2 is { 3,8 } since 3 + 2 = 5 and 8 + 2 = 10.

I suppose the code below should work but instead {3,8} I am getting {3,6,8} . I couldn't figure out how to use comparer function of std::set_intersection. What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


struct A 
{
    A ( int in ) { a = in; }
    int getNumber() { return a; }

    bool operator< ( A rhs )
    {
        return this->a < rhs.a;
    }
    int a; 
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v1{1,2,3,4,6,8};
    std::vector<A> v2{5,  7,  9,10};
    int offSet = 2;
    auto lessThanWithOffset = [offSet]( A lhs,  A rhs)
    {
        return lhs.getNumber() + offSet < rhs.getNumber();
    };

    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

    std::vector<A> v_intersection;
    std::set_intersection(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
                          v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                          std::back_inserter(v_intersection), lessThanWithOffset);

    for(auto n : v_intersection)
        std::cout << n.getNumber() << ' ';
}
```

Comment: See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), since `equiv(a, b) == !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)` so `6 == 7` because `!((6+2) < 7) && !((7+2) < 6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare), since

> The type `T` satisfies `Compare` if
>
> - The type `T` satisfies `BinaryPredicate`, and
>
> Given
>
> - `comp`, an object of type `Compare`
> - `equiv(a, b)`, an expression equivalent to `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`
>
> The following expressions must be valid and have their specified effects
>
> - For all `a`, `comp(a,a)==false`
> - If `comp(a,b)==true` then `comp(b,a)==false`
> - if `comp(a,b)==true` and `comp(b,c)==true` then `comp(a,c)==true`
> - For all `a`, `equiv(a,a)==true`
> - If `equiv(a,b)==true`, then `equiv(b,a)==true`
> - If `equiv(a,b)==true` and `equiv(b,c)==true`, then `equiv(a,c)==true`

so `equiv(A(6), A(7)) == true` because `!((6+2) < 7) && !((7+2) < 6)`

Actually, your `lessThanWithOffset` isn't complied with standard because 
`equiv(A(6), A(8)) == true` and `equiv(A(8), A(10)) == true`, but `equiv(A(6), A(10)) == false`